# Keras `ImageDataGenerator` image and mask augments differently

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, semantic-segmentation, data-augmentation

I'm training a semantic segmentation model using Keras with TensorFlow backend. I adopted `ImageDataGenerator` to do the image augmentation, including rotation, flip and shift. By following the [documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/), I created a dictionary `maskgen_args` and used it as arguments to instantiate two `ImageDataGenerator` instances.

```py
maskgen_args = dict(
    rotation_range=90,
    validation_split=VALIDATION_SPLIT
)

image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**maskgen_args)
mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**maskgen_args)
```

The training data generator is done as follows, by setting `seed` to the same value, the mask will match the image.

```py
training_data_generator = zip(
    image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        data_dir,
        target_size=(512, 512),
        color_mode='rgb',
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        class_mode=None,
        save_format='jpeg',
        seed=GENERATE_SEED,
        subset='training'
    ),
    mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        label_dir,
        target_size=(512, 512),
        color_mode='grayscale',
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        class_mode=None,
        save_format='png',
        seed=GENERATE_SEED,
        subset='training'
    )
)
```

So far, there is no problem occurred. But as I need to do some extra preprocessing (eg. normalization) only for the image but not for the mask, I created another `imagegen_args` dictionary and used it as the arguments when instantiating the `ImageDataGenerator`.

```py
maskgen_args = dict(
    rotation_range=90,
    validation_split=VALIDATION_SPLIT
)

imagegen_args = dict(
    samplewise_center=True,
    samplewise_std_normalization=True,
    channel_shift_range=10,
    brightness_range=(0.7, 1.3),
    **maskgen_args
)

image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**imagegen_args)
mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**maskgen_args)
```

When I check the output of the `training_data_generator`, problem occurred: seems the image and mask are generated separately: they surely have random rotation, but they are rotated in different angle, unlike before. Here is an example of a food image and the mask for the food.

[image: Inconsistency]

I checked the `id` of `image_datagen` and `mask_datagen`, both cases their `id` are different. I wonder why the first case they can rotate the image and mask with the same random angle, but not in the second case? What should I do to make them behave like the first case when I indeed need to give extra arguments to `image_datagen`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set

```
channel_shift_range=10,
brightness_range=(0.7, 1.3)
```

This modifies the RNG of this generator so that the Image RNG and the Mask RNG are not in sync anymore.

I propose you use a custom Sequence for this task until the KP new API is released. (see https://github.com/keras-team/governance/blob/master/rfcs/20190729-keras-preprocessing-redesign.md)

For an example of a custom Sequence, I propose an example here: https://dref360.github.io/deterministic-da/

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else struggling with this - concatenating the images and masks along the channel axis is a handy way to synchronise the augmentations

```
image_mask = np.concatenate([image, mask], axis=3)
image_mask  = augmenter.flow(image_mask).next()
image = image_mask [:, :, :, 0]
mask = image_mask [:, :, :, 1]
```